# Turning results in comma separated list

Tags: sql, list, csv

I'm using this code to get the following results:

```
Select  [Doc #], 
        [Production Number]
From    vwLiveDocuments
Where   [production number] IN
(
    SELECT  [production number]
    FROM    vwLiveDocuments
    where   [tags] LIKE N'%name of tag%'
    Group by [production number]
    Having Count (*) > 1
)
```

I'll get the following results:

```
'Doc #'     'Production number'
117611      CGI00069441
47864       CGI00069441
47865       CGI00069457
117901      CGI00069457
47866       CGI00069460
117904      CGI00069460
121479      CGI00071490
53934       CGI00071490
```

You can see duplicate results in Production number.  what i would like is to convert this list to get the following results:

```
'Production number'     'Doc #'
CGI00069441             117611,47864
CGI00069457             47865,117901
CGI00069460             47866,117904
CGI00071490             121479,53934
```

Where for every duplicate "Prod number" i would like to get a comma seperate list of the doc # that are duplicates.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: Please format your code properly when you edit the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `For xml path()` trick to do this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT [Doc #],
                [Production Number]
         FROM   vwLiveDocuments
         WHERE  [production number] IN (SELECT [production number]
                                        FROM   vwLiveDocuments
                                        WHERE  [tags] LIKE N'%20150126-Appendix B%'
                                        GROUP  BY [production number]
                                        HAVING Count (*) > 1))
SELECT [Production number],
       Stuff((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [doc #])
              FROM   cte b
              WHERE  b.[Production number] = a.[Production number]
              FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') [Doc #]
FROM   cte a
GROUP  BY [Production number]
ORDER  BY [Production Number] ASC
```

Comment: That's brilliant.. Worked like a charm.. Thanks a mil, very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry new to the site.